# Rounding down minutes to the nearest 10 minutes

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to get the date and time ten days ago.  To do this I am using the following

```
$date10DaysAgo = (get-date).adddays(-10).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

This is part of a script that runs every half hour.  Sometimes there is a delay in running the script of about a minute but I want the time part of the string to show the hour or half hour.  So If this ran at 16:31 I would need it to show 16:30 and if it ran at 17:01 it would show 17:00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting `$date10DaysAgo.Minute % 10` from the minutes:

```
$date10DaysAgo = (get-date).adddays(-10)
$date10DaysAgo = $date10DaysAgo.AddMinutes(- $date10DaysAgo.Minute % 10).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks, what is this doing exactly.  As in, what is the % 10 actually mean?

Comment: That's the modulo operator. "x % 10" indicates the remainder of dividing x by 10.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
$ago = (Get-Date).AddDays(-10)

$newMinute = ($ago.Minute / 30) * 30

$ago = Get-Date -Year $ago.Year -Month $ago.Month -Day $ago.Day -Hour $ago.Hour -Minute $newMinute 

Write-Host $ago.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```